# Handling Click Events In MVVM Lite

Tags: mvvm-light

I have a GridView and handle the click event in the Code-Behind as follows:

```
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    int itemId = ((Location)e.ClickedItem).Id;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(SectionPage), itemId))
}
```

The data is populated from the ViewModel. I would like to handle this click event in the ViewModel instead of the View, but I've not been able to figure out how to do that.

In addition, I am employing a drill down scenario, where each time an item is clicked in the GridView, it results in a similar grid with different data. The ICollection<Location> simply repeats itself three times, populating each new grid with similar data.

Currently I am using three different identical Views and ViewModels to accomplish this. It seems to me there must be a way to do this using the same View. In other words, click on an item and the view re-populates itself with a new set of data, based on the item clicked.

The data is supplied from a WebService. To obtain the new data, a separate method must be called for each View, passing in the itemId of the previous data. I cannot do this with one method as the keys are not unique across all methods.